# INDIRECT function next to IF function

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, formula

I'm not sure how this works, but is there any chance someone can help me?

I need the indirect function to work with another formula i have since it references a cell that is constantly moving (new rows are being added above it by an outlook VBA i have which means the formula reference changes) but i always need this formula to reference A2.

Here is the function I am using:

```
=IF(A2="online","ON",IF(A2="offline","OFF","ON"))
```

Where does the Indirect go? Can it even go in here?

Comment: sounds like you just need `$A$2` instead of `A2` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey use Indirect Like this:-

```
=IF(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&ROW())="online","ON",IF(INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A"&ROW())="offline","OFF","ON"))
```

This is with the assumption that your sheet name is 'Sheet1'

Hope this helps:-)

Comment: Brilliant thank you! This is working for me (how i did it just incase someone else had the same problem: =IF(INDIRECT("'sheet name '!A"&ROW(cell and number))="online","ON",IF(INDIRECT("'Sheet name '!A"&ROW(cell and number))="offline","OFF","ON"))